# What is the note division used for this fast up strum?

Tags: strumming, guitar-pro

The strumming pattern is

[image: strumming pattern]

---

So far I have this, I just cant figure out how to add that up strum as a "transition strum" if you will. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I have no musical knowledge and everything I do on guitar pro is based on guessing and checking (trial and error)...

[image: notation in guitar pro1]

Comment: Aren't there supposed to be two sixteen-notes instead of the last eight-note?

Comment: A problem for a lot of players is that the fast upstrum at the end makes it difficult to change to another chord. Resulting a lot of the time in the upstrum being all the open strings

Comment: A question in a similar spirit: [Working out strums per second given beats per minute - using guitar tabs](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25118/working-out-strums-per-second-given-beats-per-minute-using-guitar-tabs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern should look like this:

```
X:1
T:Rhythmic strumming pattern
K:None
M:4/4
L:1/8
BB BB BB BB/2B/2
```

The two notes at the end are "sixteenth notes". Each lasts half as long as the main notes in the pattern ("eighth notes").

Comment: Exactly what I meant and was looking for, thank you!!